# How to retrieve array values into individual variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have an API which returns a response in form of an array. I want to extract the elements from this array and save them in my database. I have tried using the explode function but it seems I am missing something. Below is an exact sample response from the retrieve.

```
Array
 (
[Response] => Array
    (
        [external_reference] => bablaba
        [withdraw_request_id] => babalalal
        [amount] => bababababa
        [status] => ababababab
        [message] => ababababa.
        [new_balance] => babababa
        [amount_sent] => ababababa
        [currency_sent] => ababababa
        [charge_amount] => ababababa
        [charge_currency] => babababa
        [currency] => abababaab
    )

)
```

Comment: Post code you have tried

Comment: $new_variable = $array['response']['currency']; echo $new_variable;

Answer (score 1):

You have an array `Response` inside the array `$Array`. In order to convert array element values into variables. You must navigate inside `$Array` and inside `Response` to do so you write : `$bigArray['smallArray']['element']`.

```
$external_reference = $Array['Response']['external_reference'];
$withdraw_request_id = $Array['Response']['withdraw_request_id'];
$amount = $Array['Response']['amount'];
$status = $Array['Response']['status'];
$message = $Array['Response']['message'];.
$new_balance = $Array['Response']['new_balance'];
$amount_sent = $Array['Response']['amount_sent'];
$currency_sent = $Array['Response']['currency_sent'];
$charge_amount = $Array['Response']['charge_amount'];
$charge_currency = $Array['Response']['charge_currency'];
$currency = $Array['Response']['currency'];
```

To learn more about multidimensional arrays read: [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)

Answer (score 0):

What's the point to duplicate the variables?

When you want to save the amount for exemple use `$array['response']['amount']`